# mod_wsgi cannot be loaded as Python module

Tags: django, apache, python-3.x, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to access a Django application using apache and I'm getting Internal Server Error. I've opened the logs to see what is going on and I found this:

```
[Thu Jun 23 03:10:03 2016] [notice] suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper:  /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Jun 23 03:10:03 2016] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu Jun 23 03:10:03 2016] [notice] Digest: done
[Thu Jun 23 03:10:03 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_wsgi/3.2    Python/2.6.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jun 23 03:10:10 2016] [error] [client 197.41.248.175] mod_wsgi (pid=5612): Target WSGI script '/home/TaskManagement/teamwork/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Jun 23 03:10:10 2016] [error] [client 197.41.248.175] mod_wsgi (pid=5612): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/TaskManagement/teamwork/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Jun 23 03:10:10 2016] [error] [client 197.41.248.175] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Jun 23 03:10:10 2016] [error] [client 197.41.248.175]   File "/home/TaskManagement/teamwork/wsgi.py", line 15, in <module>
[Thu Jun 23 03:10:10 2016] [error] [client 197.41.248.175]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Thu Jun 23 03:10:10 2016] [error] [client 197.41.248.175]   File "/home/py3venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
[Thu Jun 23 03:10:10 2016] [error] [client 197.41.248.175]     from django.utils.version import get_version
[Thu Jun 23 03:10:10 2016] [error] [client 197.41.248.175]   File "/home/py3venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/version.py", line 7, in <module>
[Thu Jun 23 03:10:10 2016] [error] [client 197.41.248.175]     from django.utils.lru_cache import lru_cache
[Thu Jun 23 03:10:10 2016] [error] [client 197.41.248.175]   File "/home/py3venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/lru_cache.py", line 28
[Thu Jun 23 03:10:10 2016] [error] [client 197.41.248.175]      fasttypes = {int, str, frozenset, type(None)},
[Thu Jun 23 03:10:10 2016] [error] [client 197.41.248.175]                      ^
[Thu Jun 23 03:10:10 2016] [error] [client 197.41.248.175]  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm using python 3.4, Django 1.9, apache 2.2.
and here is my apache configuration:

```
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/TaskManagement/teamwork/wsgi.py process-group=hrm.jodod.info
WSGIDaemonProcess hrm.jodod.info python-path=/home/TaskManagement:/home/py3venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup hrm.jodod.info

Alias /robots.txt /home/TaskManagement/robots.txt
Alias /favicon.ico /home/TaskManagement/favicon.ico
Alias /static/ /home/TaskManagement/static/

<Directory /path/to/mysite.com/static>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory /home/TaskManagement/teamwork>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
```

and here is my wsgi.py file:

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('/home/TaskManagement')
sys.path.append('/home/TaskManagement/teamwork')
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "{{ project_name }}.settings"
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Can anybody figure out what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Python/2.6.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

Looks like your mod_wsgi is compiled against Python 2.6.6 and you're trying to run Python3 code with it. The [Set syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) you are seeing in the error appeared in Py3. Recompile mod_wsgi and try again.

Comment: This was the problem. I had to install the source of mod_wsgi and compiled it against python 3.4 and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your wsgi.py line 9 has to be

```
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "teamwork.settings"
```

if the directory it's stored is called teamwork (your project's name)

also in your manage.py it has to be "teamwork.settings"

Comment: You can't use Django's template syntax within python files